FakeItEasy ClearRecordedCalls not working on wrapping fake
I'm using the DI container to create my fakes for integration testing. I'm calling this method for all the interfaces I need to fake in my ConfigureServices function in my Application factory:
public static IServiceCollection FakeWithBaseImplementation<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
     where T : class
{
    // Create a fake for the wrapper class
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var classImplementation = sp.GetService<T>();
    var fake = A.Fake<T>(o => o.Wrapping(classImplementation!));
    services.Remove<T>();
    services.AddTransient(_ => fake);
    return services;
}

After each test, I call this method to reset the state of the fakes:
public void ResetFakeServiceState<TServiceType>()
     where TServiceType : notnull
{
    var service = this.Services.GetRequiredService<TServiceType>();
    if (Fake.IsFake(service))
    {
        Fake.ClearRecordedCalls(service);
    }
}

However, I saw that when wrapping with the implementation, it doesn't create a Fake but a pseudo real instance and I can't seem to ClearRecordedCalls. The behavior is that if I override a method of a service, then I ClearRecordedCalls and then I execute another test, the method will still be override.
The reason I'm using wrapping is that I still want to use the original implementation AND the DI container for the class constructor. I tried using Fake with the CallsBaseMethods() option and it works for calling the base method, but it resolve the DI with Fakes inside the constructor and I want the real classes for real calls to DB and things inside it.
How I found out all this is that if I execute my tests alone, they all pass. But by executing them together, some fails.
UPDATE 1:
What I mean by pseudo Fake is that it returns true to Fake.IsFake but inside it is my service without the word Fake in front when I inspect it. I guess that's what wrapping does. But now, how to reset that?

I thought about removing it from the DI container, but then, how to add it back?

I see you register the service with AddTransient, but since you create the fake outside the delegate, it's effectively a singleton. Do you actually want it to be transient? If you do, it's an easy fix: just create the fake inside the delegate passed to AddTransient, and you'll get a new one every time it's resolved. No need to reset it.

I think your solution would work, but the issue is that I have to get the implementation in the DI container, remove it from the DI and then add it back. I can't do all of that in the delegate, I need to remove the original service before being in the delegate. However, If I do that, it is now impossible to fetch the classImplementation since it is not part of the DI container anymore. Any idea?

But the DI configuration is only done once. You can get the original implementation and reference it in the delegate. Or am I missing something?

I tested your theory. I works as it gives a new instance every time. However, it works so well that the instance in which I override the behavior is not the same to be injected in the class constructor, so the override I made do not work. Any idea? I tried AddScoped() instead, but I have an error that it can't resolve the scope service: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service '[PATH TO SERVICE}' from root provider.' when I fetch it in my test class.

Looks like you really need Fake.Reset... your timing is pretty good, because we completed it a few days ago and expect to release a new version soon!

Great! I'll be waiting for this! Will this be in a prerelease version at first? and when you say soon, how soon is it ?

It was released about 5 minutes ago, @AntoineBrisebois-Roy! Get 8.2.0.

Since version 8.2.0, we now have the options to call Fake.Reset(object fake). This is all we needed to properly use FakeItEasy in DI situations.


However, I saw that when wrapping with the implementation, it doesn't create a Fake but a pseudo real instance

I don't understand this. Can you explain what a pseudo real instance is and how it's different from a Fake? I see that T is a class, so your Fake would be a class that derives from T. Does Fake.IsFake return false?

and I can't seem to ClearRecordedCalls. The behavior is that if I
override a method of a service, then I ClearRecordedCalls and then I
execute another test, the method will still be override.

ClearRecordedCalls isn't supposed to restore any overridden behaviour. Perhaps you were looking for Fake.ClearConfiguration (which in some cases (including wrapping) doesn't work so well, so we stopped advertising it). It was replaced by Fake.Reset 8.2.0.

I'm using version 8.1.0 and ClearConfiguration is obsolete. So I'm out of options here.

@AntoineBrisebois-Roy see my comment on the question. You might not need to reset the fake at all.

I updated the question and the comments
